# Log user out after they change their password

Tags: node.js, express, session, next.js

I saw a few websites implement in this way:
their frontend make a request to the server every second, to check whether there is a change on user's session.

but other websites doesn't have this, yet they still can log user out after they change their password without waiting for user to refresh the page.

What mechanism do they use? or do you have any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways which this could be done (that comes to mind).

The first way, "polling", is what I'm guessing you've seen working, where the frontend makes a HTTP request every few seconds or minutes to check the user status.

The second way is with [web sockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API). This is a constantly open connection so data being passed back and forth along it isn't so immediately obvious in the network log, and hence you might not be seeing it.

Comment: I see, get it now.. and how to check from our browser, if our frontend application has socket connection with the server?

Comment: In chrome for example, you can go to the network tab, and then select "WS"

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is by deleting all the authentication tokens stored in the database at the time the user makes the password change.

Take this as a rough example:

```
const user = await findById(userId) // Find user

user.password = newPassword // Set new user password

user.tokens = [] // Delete all auth tokens by setting it to an empty array

await user.save() // Save user changes to the database
```

Comment: this approach won't automatically log user out from the frontend application, but thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

It can also be achieved with [server sent events](https://rathoreaparna678.medium.com/understanding-server-sent-events-with-node-js-652f8a3c3826)